Error importing PRDownloader, AndroidPDFViewer Github library on Android Studio
Getting error while syncing library from Github.
AndroidPDFViewer: enter link description here
PRDownloader : enter link description here
Android Studio Build Output is showing this error:

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

> Could not find android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.1.aar (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1).
    Searched in the following locations:
        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/barteksc/android-pdf-viewer/3.2.0-beta.1/android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.1.aar
        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/barteksc/android-pdf-viewer/3.2.0-beta.1/android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.1.jar

Note: Many other library from Github, JitPack is not working.

PDF library is working by changing it : implementation 'com.github.DImuthuUpe:AndroidPdfViewer:3.1.0-beta.1'
